How to enable only a subset of Polars' crate features?
I am using Polars in Rust. I have noticed that compile times drop significantly and give a smaller binary when using the polars-core crate instead of the polars crate. However, it's discouraged to use this "internal" crate.
In my Cargo.toml I specify my Polars deps as:
polars = { version = "0.41.0", features = ["dtype-struct", "lazy", "timezones"] }

Is it possible to include only the subset of features in the polars crate that I'm actually using?

Do you mean like default-features = false? https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html?highlight=default-features#dependency-features

That appears to be just what I was looking for. Thanks! I'm happy to accept an answer I you provide one.

Crates can have some features enabled by default. To disable those features, you can pass default-features = false as an option for that dependency in your Cargo.toml:
[dependencies]
polars = { version = "0.41.0", default-features = false }

This will disable all default features and you can then enable the features you want with features = ["dtype-struct", ...].
Documentation
